# Exersice 1-13 from K&R

Tags: c

I am doing the K&R book.
If i check a == then everything works but if I check !=, then no histogram is printed. 
This works

```
  while( (c = getchar()) != EOF  )
    {
      if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c =='\n')
    {
      state = OUT;
      if(wc>0)
        ++numOfWords[wc];
      wc = 0;
    }
      else
    if(state == OUT)
      state = IN;

      if(state = IN)
    ++wc;
    }
```

but changing the if section to this does not:

```
    if(c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c !='\n'){
    if(state == OUT){
      state = IN;
      ++wc;}
    else
      ++wc;
      }
      else
    {
      state = OUT;
      if(wc>0)
        ++numOfWords[wc];
      wc = 0;
    }
    }
```

I want every character that is not a tab or a space or a newline. So i wrote `c != '\t' || c!= ' ' || c!= '\n'.` which i take to mean as
`If c is not (!=) space(' ') then its 1(true) OR(||) if c is not (!=) tab('\t') then its 1 OR(||) ...so on.`
 And if any one of the OR statement is true then the whole statement is true and body should execute, so  why isn't it executing?

Thanks for noticing the typo in first snippet, I corrected it, but I want to ask is why doesn't the second snippet work?

Answer:
This works perfectly:

```
if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c !='\n' && c != '"' && c!= '.' && c != ','){
if(state == OUT){
  state = IN;
  ++wc;}
else
  ++wc;
  }
  else
{
  state = OUT;
  if(wc>0)
    ++numOfWords[wc];
  wc = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet

```
 if(state = OUT)
 ...   
 if(state = IN)
```

is wrong. Change this to

```
  if(state == OUT)
  ...
  if(state = IN)
```

After that if your first snippet of code works well then change

```
if(c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c !='\n')
```

in your second snippet to

```
if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c !='\n')
```

Comment: Basically i want a filter. If you are not a space, come right in, then if you are not a tab come furtherin and so on?

Comment: @aamermoquim; I did't understand what you are confused with?

Comment: @aamermoquim; If you will use `if(c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c !='\n')  ` then suppose `c` is not equal to `' '` then the condition is true although next character is whiteline (`\n`,`\t` etc) character or not.

Comment: @haccks; thank u, i understand now. added working code to question.

Answer (score 1):

if you with to negate the whole if stament try if(!(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c =='\n')) or its logical equivalent if( c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c == '\n')). Negating the individuals elements is not enough. You have to change the or's to and's.

Comment: See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) and  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 0):

Every character is either "not a space", "not a tab", or "not a newline". A tab, for instance, is "not a space" and "not a newline". So that if-condition will never be false. It sounds like you want to look for characters which are "not a space" AND "not a tab" AND "not a newline".

Comment: This is exactly right. If I feed tab to this code then not being a space, it would be true and the statement would execute(short circuit). What is needed is to check each conditional one after another. If its not a tab, is it a space, if not is it still a newline, if none of those then we wants it. That is the job of && not ||.